# Bootstrap footer 'fit' issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sticky-footer

Hi there having a problem with my bootstrap footer.

I added this OK and sticks to bottom of page as required. I notice however that viewing the page on a mobile device (iphone 5s and 6) that the page scrolls left to right which it shouldn't do as the information fits horizontally on the screen. I would only expect vertical scrolling. Its as if the footer width is more than 100% causing the mobile to 'unlock' horizontally, can anyone help with this?

Just to add no erroneous horizontal scroll bar appears in the desktop view of the same page, regardless of how the window is sized

Here is the code

```
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 text-center">
  <p>
    <a href="/privacy">Privacy</a>
    |
    <a href="/terms">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>
    |
    <a href="/contact">Contact Us</a>
    <br>
    2015
  </p>
</div>
```

and from the css

```
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.container {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 680px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.container .text-muted {
  margin: 20px 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

add css style to body element

```
padding:0px;
```

Also do not forget to add meta tag in your head element

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```